# Render image from S3 in IE11/Edge with Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, internet-explorer, amazon-s3, mime-types, microsoft-edge

I have a set of images stored on S3 that should be displayed on the browser. These images have a content type of `application/octet-stream` and can be viewed in Chrome and Firefox.

My understanding is that Internet Explorer cannot view `application/octet-stream` content, or it is unable to realize that the S3 object is actually an image.

I've tried to upload new versions of my images onto S3 and manually adding a Metadata Header/Value pair of `Content-Type` and `image/png` (using the S3 console, not CLI). However, I still see the same `application/octet-stream` on IE.

Is it possible to configure my application (Angular4/SpringBoot/Tomcat) to tell IE to look at that type of content, or am I looking at the wrong place in S3?

Comment: If you changed it in the console, but still see it in the browser, then either your bucket hasn't fully propagated the change throughout S3 (which sometimes takes a few seconds when modifying an existing object) or the object has been cached by the browser.  Note that for **any** browser to render `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` as an image, technically, is wrong.  `image/png` is correct, so you need to use that with uploads.  For once, IE seems to be doing the right thing by not rendering the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my backend, where I set my AWS S3 api I was setting the response headers to 'application/octet-stream'.